# data updation of a column in sql table based on another column of same table

Tags: sql, database

i have 2 table with four & five column in sql 
  in 1st  table four column like ID - Parant - Position - Assign Id (ID+Position)

in 2nd table five column like  assign ID - ID - L1- L2- L3

assign id & ID automatic update from 1st table
L1,L2,L3 based on assign id & ID column

i want a query for L1 column for update data like this procedure

find (ID+Left) in assign Id column and if match with records then copy record from ID column whose matched in assign Id and paste in L1 column

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use update with join to update table column.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07622

Comment: SQL:  update a2 set a2.name = a1.name from a2 inner join a1 on a1.id=a2.a1_id;

Comment: @Manish: If you find the previous comment working for you then please close this question by accepting the answer.